# How to apply multiple styles based on multiple conditions in ng-style directive?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-style

In angular, I need to apply different style attributes based on different conditions but its not working this way and I only can apply 2 conditions with conditional expression.

```
<div ng-style="
    (status=="up")  ?{'background-color':'green' ,'color':'green'}
    (status=="down")?{'background-color':'red'   ,'color':'red'}
    (status=="idle")?{'background-color':'yellow','color':'yellow'}
    (status=="")    ?{'background-color':'grey'  ,'color':'grey'}
">
```

It would be better if you know any way to pass attribute to a function that returns style obj for ng-style like bellow which is weirdly not working!

```
$scope.styleFn(status,attr) {
        (status=="up")  ?{attr:'green'}
        (status=="down")?{attr:'red'}
        (status=="idle")?{attr:'yellow'}
        (status=="")    ?{attr:'grey'}
}

<div ng-style="styleFn('up','background-color')">
```

Answer (score 4):

yes you can use a function to specify a more complex condition.

```
var style = {
  'up': {'background-color':'green' ,'color':'green'},
  'down': {'background-color':'red' ,'color':'red'},
  'idle': {'background-color':'yellow' ,'color':'yellow'},
  'default': {'background-color':'grey'  ,'color':'grey'}
}

$scope.applyStyle = function(status) {
    //the status is the key to get the target style
    return status ? style[status] : style['default']; 
)};
```

then the template

```
<div ng-style="applyStyle(status)"></div>
```

Comment: Thats right but how do you pass attribute to the function and generate customized style? it is not weirdly working as it should.

Comment: just pass the attribute to the function (up, down, idle, or empty string) and the function will do its magic applying the right style to the element.

Comment: please check my question again. status is fine, attr is not working. thats the weird part. if you pass `'color'` it does return `{'color': '#ff0000'}` for example but not showing in DOM.

Comment: the ternary operator must have even the : to be a complete expression (see here: (status=="up")  ?{attr:'green'}) . a part from that , why should you need an attr parameter? won't be enough only the status?

Comment: no there are border/color/background/... should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-class as well.

```js
function DemoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.status = 'up'
}
```

```css
.green {
    color: green;
    background-color:green;
}
.red {
    color: red;
    background-color:red
}
.yellow {
    color: yellow;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
    
    <table ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
        <tr ng-class="{'green': status == 'up','red':status== 'down' ,'yellow': status== 'idle' } ">
            <td style="color:white;">Your status is {{status}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```