# how to apply two different styles for a html based on a boolean

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a html tag for example like below

```
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
```

I want to apply two different styles to the same input tag based on a boolean.

Let's say if I have true - I want to set

```
margin-top:40 px;
```

If the the value is false - I don't want to set any margin-top

I tried using ngStyle as a example like below

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color':person.country === 'UK' ? 'green' : 'red' }"></<div>
```

**ngStyle** didn't work out for me. The styles were not being applied.

Need help if there is any other way to handle this scenario.

Comment: ng-style is an Angular directive. Are you using Angular in your application? Or are you just rying to have conditional style in vanilla JS?

Comment: As noted in Dr. Tenma's answer you'll need to use JS.  May also want to consider css if there are a lot of elements.  References:  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_style.asp, https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60805814/change-several-css-based-on-boolean.

Comment: If you are using Angular, please include the angular tag. There are specific duplicates of this question for Angular, and specific ones for non-Angular.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply multiple styles based on multiple conditions in ng-style directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44210899/how-to-apply-multiple-styles-based-on-multiple-conditions-in-ng-style-directive)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```js
var bool = true;

var input = document.getElementById("fname")

if (bool === true) {
input.style.marginTop = "40px";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
```

Comment: ```document``` is not available by the time this loads. So it is **undefined** .Any other options?

Comment: Have you placed your script before the closing body tag?

Comment: btw this is an **angular** app, There is no traditional ```head``` and ```body``` tags but yes the app is all up and running

Comment: can you use [viewContentLoaded](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView#event-$viewContentLoaded)?